# Pass the value of .$row[something] for executing another query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dashboard table(MySQL) that prints its values to a html table(dashboard ID is hidden) in a php file(dashboard.php), plus another column for a button which calls another php(deletedashboard.php) file to delete the row. What I need is upon clicking the button I need to get the dashboard id of the specific row and forward it to deletedashboard.php so i can execute the query to delete the row.

the table in dashboard.php:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("select dashboardid, date, message, remarks from dashbaord");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   echo "<table class=\"table table-striped table-bordered table-hover\"><tr><th>Date</th><th>Message</th><th>Remarks</th><th></th></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo "<tr><td style=\"display:none;\">".$row["dashboardid"]."</td><td>".$row["date"]."</td><td>".$row["message"]."</td><td>".$row["remarks"]."</td><td><center><button formaction=\"deletedashboard.php\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-ok\" ><strong> Delete</strong></button>";
                      }
   echo "</table>";
   } else {
   echo "0 results";
   }
?>
```

deletedashboard.php:

```
session_start();

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "") or die (mysql_error($conn));
mysql_select_db("mydb", $conn);

$ID = *I need to get the ID from the .$row["dashboardid"] from dashboard.php*

$query = "DELETE from dashboard WHERE dashboardid=$ID";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
    echo mysql_error($conn);
} else {
    header("Location: ../dashboard.php");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use href

```
<a href="deletedashboard.php?id=<?php echo $row['dashboardid']; ?>">Delete</a>
```

update your code like that :-

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo "<tr><td style=\"display:none;\">".$row["dashboardid"]."</td>
   <td>".$row["date"]."</td><td>".$row["message"]."</td><td>".$row["remarks"]."</td>
   <td><center>
    <a href="deletedashboard.php?id=<?php echo $row['dashboardid']; ?>">Delete</a>
    }
```

And `deletedashboard.php`

```
$ID = $_GET["id"];//get id
$query = "DELETE from dashboard WHERE dashboardid=$ID";
```

Comment: thank you for this code, it works. but what if  I need to get values from 2 IDs? e.g. id of the <a href> and id of one of the <td> in the table?

Comment: <a href="deletedashboard.php?id=<?php echo $row['dashboardid']; ?>&id2=5">Delete</a>

Comment: so I can get the values by
$ID = $_GET["id"];
$ID2 = $_GET["id2"];
?

Comment: you get value like that

Answer (score 0):

**Change :**

```
<?php
. . . 
. . .    
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td style=\"display:none;\">".$row["dashboardid"]."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row["date"]."</td><td>".$row["message"]."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row["remarks"]."</td>":
   // just append $row['dashboardid'] with page url
   echo "<td><center><button formaction='deletedashboard.php?id=".$row['dashboardid']."' type='button' class='btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-ok' ><strong> Delete</strong></button>";
}
   . . . 
   . . . 
?>
```

Catch the `id` with **`$_GET`** in `deletedashboard.php` like:

```
session_start();

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "") or die (mysql_error($conn));
mysql_select_db("mydb", $conn);

$ID = $_GET["id"];  // here you can get your $row['dashboardid']

$query = "DELETE from dashboard WHERE dashboardid=$ID";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
    echo mysql_error($conn);
} else {
    header("Location: ../dashboard.php");
}
```

**UPDATES:**

append all `ids` whatever you want, with using comma,as:

```
formaction='deletedashboard.php?ids=".$row['dashboardid'].",".$row['someother_id'].",".$someStatic_id.";
```

and

*catching these Ids*: Use **`explode()` function** to get array of ids like:

```
$ids[] = explode(',',$_GET['ids']);
$id1 = $ids[0];
$id2 = $ids[1];
// and so on...
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to get multiple ids and pass it to the deletedashboard.php? for example, i want to get the ID of the <button>, and the ID of a <td>?

Comment: @user3514806, Accept answer if working. - Just pass them with **comma  `,`  seperated**, like `deletedashboard.php?ids=".$row['dashboardid'].",".$someother_id."....`.

Comment: but how will I get them individually again for my query? e.g. delete dashboard where id=$row['dashboardid'] and insert dashboard (id) values ($someother_id)